# Why I am getting this warning/error message each time I open terminal?How should I fix this?

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

-bash: /usr/local/bin/python3: No such file or directory
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3 and that PATH is
set properly.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from a broken installation of `virtualenvwrapper`. It seems you've installed `virtualenvwrapper` using `/usr/local/bin/python3` but later removed that python.

The error comes from `~/.bashrc`. Edit it, search for something like `source virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh` or `. virtualenvwrapper.sh` and comment out or remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Check virtualenvwrapper is installed.
2. Open your .bashrc file.
3. Run the below commands:
```

> export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenv
>
> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
>
> ```
> workon <virtual_env_name_of_your_choice>
> ```
>
> which python

```
4. Check the python version.
5. If you want to change the python of your virtualenv, then follow the steps below:
```

> vi .bashrc or vi .zshrc
>
> alias python=python3

```
6. Open a new terminal.
```

> which python
>
> workon
>
> which python

You are all set with virtualenv set to python3 by default.